# Some array elements (cut and paste) return Invalid numeric literal while others do not

Tags: php, arrays

I have made a test array for a standart Horoscope task (input your birth date in DD-MM and get a horoscope). The task itself is obvious. But some array elements behave unnaturally though I used 'cut-and-paste' from the ones that work well. Unless I double slash some array elements browser returns 'Invalid numeric literal'. I've checked them all and found nothing suspicious. Maybe you'll help me?

> ```
> $horoscope = [
>           [mktime(0,0,1,03,21),mktime(23,59,59,04,20),'Horoscope for Aries'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,04,21),mktime(23,59,59,05,20),'Horoscope for Taurus'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,05,21),mktime(23,59,59,06,20),'Horoscope for Gemini'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,06,21),mktime(23,59,59,07,20),'Horoscope for Cancer'],
>         //[mktime(0,0,1,07,21),mktime(23,59,59,08,20),'Horoscope for Leo'],
>         //[mktime(0,0,1,08,21),mktime(23,59,59,09,20),'Horoscope for Virgo'],
>         //[mktime(0,0,1,09,21),mktime(23,59,59,10,20),'Horoscope for Libra'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,10,21),mktime(23,59,59,11,20),'Horoscope for Scorpio'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,11,21),mktime(23,59,59,12,20),'Horoscope for Sagittarius'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,12,21),mktime(23,59,59,01,20),'Horoscope for Capricorn'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,01,21),mktime(23,59,59,02,20),'Horoscope for Aquarius'],
>           [mktime(0,0,1,02,21),mktime(23,59,59,03,20),'Horoscope for Pisces']
> ];
> ```

And so on with 'foreach' to compare with the input time stamp. And the strings commented always make 'Invalid numeric literal'. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: When you include a 0 at the start of a number, this is assumed to be octal.  So any value such as 08 and 09 will be invalid.

Comment: Thanks, but then why the others work?
UPD.: Converted all to 1-digit (where needed) format: script delivers the same result.

Comment: Because they are valid octal numbers (01-07 are the same as 1-7)

Comment: Have you tried just removing any leading `0`'s in the numbers?

Comment: Yes, you were right. Great thanks! I've changed them in ONE mktime of the TWO and was wondering why the script doesn't work. You helped me much! One more small step done.

Comment: As @NigelRen said... Eg. `[mktime(0,0,1,7,21),mktime(23,59,59,8,20),'Horoscope for Leo']`

Comment: Thanks again!  So hard to get used to it :)